Does `ReadAsMultipartAsync` use preloaded buffer data?
If I use Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync() to limit the buffer size, does Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync() read the content from this preloaded buffer, or does it read the content fresh?
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("uploadFile")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile()
        {
            if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, "Content must be multipart/form-data.");

            try
            {
                try
                {
                    await Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync(MaxFileSizeBytes);
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,ex.Message);
                }

                var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());

                var files = provider.Contents?.ToList();
                if (!files.Any())
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Need at least one file.");

                var isUploadSuccess = await _service.UploadFile (files);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, isUploadSuccess);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Write($"Error occurred during the uploada, ex);
                throw;
            }
        }


I see that the documentation uses CopyToAsync() to create a MemoryStream. Do I need this MemoryStream to access the preloaded buffer, or can ReadAsMultipartAsync read directly from the preloaded buffer?
LoadIntoBufferAsync

What happens when you run your code, any errors or what?

@PoulBak I don't see any errors, I'm just looking at it from an optimization perspective and want to know if it reads the same content twice.

This question is similar to: Multiple Calls to HttpContent ReadAsAsync. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
